# Which mappings to use for GET requests?

Tags: java, rest

I have a question about URI that should represent my RESTful application.
I've read many topics on different resources but I still unsure how should I implement the following situation:

I have 3 methods in my controller:

```
List<Books> getAllBooks()
List<Books> getBooksByTitle(String title)
List<Books> getBooksByAuthor(String author)
```

It's obvious that I should choose `"/books"` URI for the 1st method but if I map `"/books/title?"` or `"/books/author?"` for next methods an exception "Ambiguous mapping" is throwed. `"/books/title/"` and `"/books/author/"` doesn't seem to be a good choice.

What solution can I advice me?

Comment: You can make it in one single endpoint using parameters, like /books?author=AuthorX&title=TitleB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `GET /book` - get all books
- `GET /book/{id}` - get one book with specific `id`
- `GET /book?title={title}&author={author}` - get all books with given `title` and `author`

I predict, that you could have more options for search, so I would prefer another endpoint for it:

- `POST /book/search` *BODY: {"author": "aaa", "title": "bbb"}* - get all books according to given search request (we use **body** here, so we could not use `GET` here, because `GET` request could be cashed by any part of network within alive period).

**Note:** *in my opinion*, `title` or `author` is not a domain object and therefore I do not use endpoints like `GET /book/author/{author}` or `GET /book/title/{title}`. **BUT** I do not mind to use endpoints for one single book, like:

- `GET /book/{id}/author` - get all authors for given book
- `GET /book/{id}/title` - get title for given book

I hope I have answered you question.

Comment: Agree with the first part, but the `POST` endpoint... does it need to be a post in order to have a json payload, cant you use `GET` here also?

Comment: @vikingsteve It needs to be POST to have a json payload, but in the example given it could just be query parameters

Comment: About the note: you don't need to project your resource directly to a specific domain object.

Comment: in GET /book/search case how can I ensure that at least 1 parameter will be passed? If author and title are required=false then the searchMethod will anyway process the request

Comment: @Pavel it is up to you. In endpoint you get the body and convert json into an object. Then you go throug this object and create e.g. SQL statement and then return the result. If Body is empty (I mean like `{}` and not criteria found), you could retrive `empty` result (this is preferable to me) or all available books (do not forget about paging in case of big collection)

Answer (score 1):

To be RESTful, you should use a search pattern:

```
List<Books> getAllBooks()                    --> /books
List<Books> getBooksByTitle(String title)    --> /books?title=...
List<Books> getBooksByAuthor(String author)  --> /books?author=...
```

because authors and titles aren't a subresource of your books.

If you were searching for a book by its unique code though, you should use `/books/{id}` as you're identifying a specific resource.
This kind of pattern allows you to identify subresources when needed, for example, if you want the genres of a specific book:

```
List<BookGenres> getGenresFromBook(int idBook) --> /books/{id}/genres
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Richardson Maturity Model, you should consider your endpoints as resources. 
Which means you could consider one resource with query parameters to filter your result:

- GET /books
- GET /books?title={title}
- GET /books?author={author}

Another approach could be to consider a 'titles' resource and an 'authors' resource which would provide a link to a book entity

- GET /books
- GET /titles/{title} // Returns a list of matching titles with a link /book/{id}
- GET /authors/{author} // Returns a list of matching authors with a link /book/{id}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring you could have something along these lines

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
public class BookController{
    private BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService){
        this.bookService=bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public List<Book> getBooks(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams){
        return bookService.getBooks(allRequestParams);
    }
}
```

You could then call the api like:

localhost:8080/api/books?author=AuthorName

localhost:8080/api/books?title=BookTitle

And you can access the filter from the map like allRequestParams.get("title");

Also you can implement your filter entity in order to ensure that filters are set-up correctly such as:

```
public class BookFilter{
    private String title;
    private String authorFilter;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
    // And then in the Controller you can use the following
        @GetMapping()
        public List<Book> getBooks(BookFilter bookFilter){
           return bookService.getBooks(bookFilter);
        }
```

Comment: If you're using spring boot, you may just want to specify the different parameters as optionals using the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PathVariable to search the result by the field.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/book")
@RestController
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping
    List<Book> getAllBooks()

    @GetMapping("/title={title}")
    List<Book> getBooksByTitle(@PathVariable String title)

    @GetMapping("/author={author}")
    List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(@PathVariable String author)
}
```

Call the restfull api like:

```
'/book'
'/book/title=xxx'
'/book/author=xxx'
```

Comment: You shouldn't and often cannot use path variables like this; at least use `/book/title/{xxx}`. IT is recommended to isolate the path variables. Not sure if a spec forbids it though.